# Run a function or route in whole application in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create an application where i have a user activity log. I dont want to write a special function in all the pages. I just want to metnion it once and run on all the pages or controller where ever i go. Which keep showing on the header.blade.php. And i want to keep using that log all time.

I have a function with like this.

```
public function headerLogs()
    {
        $latestActivities = Activity::with('user')->latest()->limit(10)->get();
        return view('layouts.header')->with('logs', $latestActivities);
    }
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Paste your code in helper.php and auto load in composer. Or use can use trait

Comment: Yes i have this code in my helper.php. How can i use trait?

Comment: I guess view::composer is one option? Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel has built-in functionality for that: [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers). They are what you use if you want some data to be in every view that is loaded (of course you specify which views exactly)

So from the docs we would create a service provider for our view composer:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ActivitiesComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {    
        // Using Closure based composers...
        view()->composer('layout.header.activity', function ($view) {

        $latestActivities = Activity::with('user')->latest()->limit(10)->get();

        $view->with('logs', $latestActivities);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And then you register your `ActivitiesComposerServiceProvider` service provider by simply adding it to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

So now you can simply `@include('layout.header.activity')` and the logs will show with no extra line of code in your controller or view

Comment: I just did the way you mentioned here. Composer is the way to do this. But i am not getting why its throughing error like this: 

`Undefined variable: logs (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravelCRM/resources/views/layouts/header.blade.php)`

I have also registered my composer with name `HeaderLog` in my app.php file, here is how i did it register `App\Providers\HeaderLogs::class,`

Comment: Did you put the correct name for the view in your composer? My code example has *layout.header.activity*, yours may be named differently `view()->composer('layout.header.activity')`.

Comment: Yes i made it, `layout.header` so whole header can have access to that. I didnt made different file for `activity`.

Comment: This problem i am finding in only `Closure` approach. Rest if i mentioned it like this `view()->composer(
            'layouts.header', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\HeaderComposer'
        );` then its working.

Comment: OK got the issue :) i was making mistake in `layout.header` it should be `layouts` :)

Comment: Thank you so much :) It helped me a lot to make things easer :)

Answer (score 1):

In your base controller:

`view()->composer('layouts.header',  function($view){ 
  //your code for header logs which gives $logActivites.
  $view->with('logs',  $logActivites);
}`

So, whenever your view layouts.header will be created, this `$logActivites` will be available.

Comment: Sorry I am using from mobile not able to use proper tools to render the code.

Comment: Sure, your approch is completely correct. But i dont know why i am not able to get it done. with the clouser approch.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone had a situation when one variable had to be accessible in every view (blade) file. One possible solution – letting the service provider load our global view information. For Example, type this in your service provider.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // Using view composer for specific view
        view()->composer('welcome',function($view) {
            $view->with('latestActivities', Activity::with('user')->latest()->limit(10)->get());
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can access the latestActivities variable from all you view files